# How to handle errors in VBS

Tags: vbscript

The script below was pieced together to loop through sub-folders and files within a given path.  For each file I am grabbing the path, file name, file size, file type, owner, and dates associate with the file.  I have numerous directories where I am performing this same task so I created a small batch file that calls the vbs and outputs the data to a text file (program.vbs echo >> output.txt).

My question is, how can I incorporate some type of error handling? The script fails on one specific file, but the file does not appear to be corrupt or have any unique naming characteristics so I have no clue why its failing.

Any input would be greatly appreciated as I'm sure my script has many flaws and I would prefer to learn the correct way of doing things.

Update / Solution:

```
Set fs = WScript.CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)

  For Each Subfolder In Folder.SubFolders 
    On Error Resume Next 
    If Err Then
        WScript.Echo "Error accessing " & folder & ": " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    Else
        Set files = SubFolder.Files 
            For Each file In files
            On Error Resume Next
            If Err Then
                WScript.Echo "Error accessing " & folder & ": " & Err.Description 
                Err.Clear
            Else
                        strFilePath = File.Path
                    strFileName = File.Name
                        strFileSize = File.Size
                        strFileType = File.Type
                        strFileDateCreated = File.DateCreated
                        strFileDateLastAccessed = File.DateLastAccessed
                        strFileDateLastModified = File.DateLastModified
                Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:")
                Set objFileSecuritySettings = _
                objWMIService.Get("Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting=""" & replace(file, "\", "\\") & """")
                intRetVal = objFileSecuritySettings.GetSecurityDescriptor(objSD)

                If intRetVal = 0 Then
                                strFileOwner = objSD.Owner.Domain & "\" & objSD.Owner.Name
                Else
                    strFileOwner = "Couldn't retrieve security descriptor."
                End If
                        Wscript.Echo strFilePath & "~" &_
                            strFileName & "~" &_
                            strFileSize & "~" &_
                            strFileType & "~" &_
                            strFileDateCreated & "~" &_
                            strFileDateLastAccessed & "~" &_
                            strFileDateLastModified & "~" &_
                            strFileOwner        
            End If
        Next
        ShowSubFolders Subfolder
    End If  
 Next

End Sub

ShowSubFolders fs.GetFolder("C:\Test")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get turned off but in `VBScript` error handling can seem odd, here is how you do it:

```
Dim i
' Turn on error Handling
On Error Resume Next


'Code here that you want to catch errors from

' Error Handler
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
   ' Error Occurred / Trap it
   On Error Goto 0 ' But don't let other errors hide!
   ' Code to cope with the error here
End If
On Error Goto 0 ' Reset error handling.
```

And if this was an ASP classic site there are ways to set IIS up to create xml error log files.

Comment: Thank you Meda. I should have been more clear in stating I found some basic information on the On Error Resume Next, but was unclear how to implement it.  Your comment was very helpful and added a couple lines that I am currently testing.

Comment: Yes I had to do this when debugging legacy code, we were coding an asp classic system using notepad, this was the only way I found to handle errors, and also the xml files. what a pain

Comment: Is there a way to partially process the error and then reraise it? In VBS the `err.raise` only works for the custom errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've sort of rewritten your script. If it was only a partial script then fair enough, otherwise I don't think it would have worked. In fact if it's failing on "a file", it might be the non-existent file object initially referenced?

```
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Sub ShowSubFolders(folder)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim subfolder, file
    ' Was the folder parameter a folder object? If not then Folder.Subfolders won't work. So substituting with the below:
    For Each subfolder In fso.GetFolder(Folder).SubFolders
        ' If we have an error at this point then I can only imagine the specified folder doesn't exist or you don't have access to it
        ' Also where is "File.Path" etc coming from? I see no file objects at this point. So I'm removing all references to the file here.
        If Err Then
            WScript.Echo "Error accessing " & folder & ": " & Err.Description ' Assumes folder is a path rather than an object, otherwise should be folder.Path
            Err.Clear ' Clear error for next loop
        Else
            For Each file In subfolder.Files
                ' Again if you get an error here then I can only see it being due to permissions, and either way if you 
                ' errored on creating a file object then you won't have access to that file object's properties like file.Path 
                ' etc, so again removing all of that. However I think it's extremely unlikely you'd get an error here anyway.
                If Err Then
                    WScript.Echo "Error getting file object: " & Err.Description
                Else
                    Dim strFilePath, strFileName, strFileSize, strFileType, strFileDateCreated, strFileDateLastAccessed, strFileDateLastModified
                    strFilePath = file.Path
                    strFileName = file.Name
                    strFileSize = file.Size
                    strFileType = file.Type
                    strFileDateCreated = file.DateCreated
                    strFileDateLastAccessed = file.DateLastAccessed
                    strFileDateLastModified = file.DateLastModified

                    ' I'm not changing anything in the WMI section as I've never done security via WMI
                    Dim objWMIService, objFileSecuritySettings, intRetVal, strFileOwner
                    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:") 
                    Set objFileSecuritySettings = _
                    objWMIService.Get("Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting=""" & replace(file, "\", "\\") & """")

                    intRetVal = objFileSecuritySettings.GetSecurityDescriptor(objSD)
                    If intRetVal = 0 Then
                        strFileOwner = objSD.Owner.Domain & "\" & objSD.Owner.Name
                    Else
                        strFileOwner = "Couldn't retrieve security descriptor."
                    End If

                    Wscript.Echo strFilePath & "~" &_
                    strFileName & "~" &_
                    strFileSize & "~" &_
                    strFileType & "~" &_
                    strFileDateCreated & "~" &_
                    strFileDateLastAccessed & "~" &_
                    strFileDateLastModified & "~" &_
                    strFileOwner
                End If
                Err.Clear ' Clear the error for the next loop - putting this here since you aren't doing error
                ' checking in the WMI part; don't want to carry errors from here over into the next iteration
            Next
        End If
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

ShowSubFolders "C:\temp"
```